# Arduino UNO generate square wave, which is exactly the same with trigger pulse, but with a time delay

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new in using Arduino so please forgive me if my question is too simple.

I need to generate a square wave with exactly the same duty cycle and frequency with the trigger pulse. The trigger pulse is 15 Hz with two rising edges in each cycle. Besides, I need to introduce an adjustable delay between them.

Is anyone can tell me how to do it please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd forget the idea of "generating a square wave". Instead I'd just watch the incoming signal and replicate it x time in the future. If you see a rising edge then think "I need to generate a rising edge in x ms" - and the same with a falling edge.

Comment: thank you but the rising edges in triggering pulses  are not importatnt. It is for reminding when using interrupts as it will be trigger twice in one cycle.

Comment: @chris I don't understand your comment. If the triggering pulse is not important, then why should the output be exactly the same? Majenko suggested just writing code, that reads the pin (maybe through interrupts, maybe without), delaying and then outputting that value onto the output pin

Comment: how can you have two rising edges in a cycle?

Comment: I mean exactly the same in terms of duty cycle and frequency. I tried but the phase between two pulses are not stable.

Comment: Here are the main codes:
void loop() {
  InputState = digitalRead(interruptPin);

if (InputState == HIGH){
  delay (DelayTime);
  digitalWrite (OutPin, HIGH);
  delay (TriggerPeakDuration);
  digitalWrite (OutPin, LOW);
  delay (T - TriggerPeakDuration - DelayTime);
  
}

Comment: please put the explanation and the code into your question .... format the code properly

Comment: `digitalWrite()` and `digitalRead()` are extremely slow. Plus the `loop()` function is called in a loop, so the CPU has overhead when the function returns and is called again (jumps). This all introduces delay in the execution if your check-and-set-pin logic, thus the result you see is totally expected. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0Hr24QDD-s.

Comment: You may just want to rewrite it to use interrupts and a timer. As in, interrupt fires, you set the output, arm a timer with some expiry time, the timer interrupt fires, you unset the output. CPU can mostly sleep then, too.. If that's not possible, at least use `digitalWriteFast()` and friends, and unrolled loops..